# google places api consumes 10 request but I am doing only 1

Tags: r, google-places-api, google-places, googleway

I am doing a request to Google Places Api in R, I am only doing the next request:

```
library(googleway)

latlon<-c(40.395536 ,-3.709588)
result<-google_places(search_string =  "Hospital",
                        location = latlon,
                        key = APIkey,
                        keyword = "Hospital",
                        language = "es")
```

It is 1 request but when I look in the Google Places console, it consumes 10 request. Why? What is the problem?

Comment: I ran your code and it only shows 1 request in Google's console. Have you given your key to anyone else/do you share a key? Are you sure running this command once results in 10 requests?

Comment: Hi, in the control panel appears 1 request, but if you see inside quotas tab, you will 10 request. It looks like I did 1 request but Google used 10.

Comment: Ok I found the culprit: ["Note: The Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota"](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

Comment: Ooooooh!, That is a shame, so the problem is not with the package else the limitations of Google. Well, thanks a lot folks, nice and useful package!

Comment: you're welcome; glad it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage)

> Note: The Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is, each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google Places API Web Service as part of your Google Maps APIs Premium Plan contract, the multiplier may be different.

So what you're seeing is expected behaviour